# LDAP Role Mapping - Working, but not Assigning

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I have setup the ldap module for Drupal 7 - everything is working as it should, apart from when a user logs into the site the role defined for that person isn't been assigned to their profile, they remain just an authenticated user.

When I run a test on their username it shows that the user should be part of the correct role.

In the error log I can see it is failing when granting a single authorisation with the following error:

```
LdapAuthorizationConsumerDrupalRole.grantSingleAuthorization() failed to grant xxx the role Delegate because role does not exist
```

However the Delegate role is setup and present.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

--

Just to note that I found the solution - don't use capitals in your roles.  Changing Delegate to delegate fixed it.  I will put this as the answer when my 8 hour self answer delay lapses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution - which made me kick myself :p

In order to get the role mapping working the role names have to start with a lower case letter - so in my example I changed the role name from Delegate to delegate and it is all working now.